# how to get nested json decode data in php.

Tags: facebook-graph-api, json

i Want to fetch this data using json decode. Please Help..

So far i come up with this script but i unable to fetch the second last and last 'name' and 'link' under actions. please help..

```
foreach($json['data'] as $post)
{
$name1 = $post['actions']['name'];
$name2 = $post['actions']['name']['name'];
$name3 = $post['actions']['name']['name']['name'];
```

But this is not working please help i want to get all name and link data from following example its a snippet from facebook graph api..

> ```
>     {
>       "data": [
>         {
>
>           "actions": [
>             {
>               "name": "Comment", 
>               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxidxxxx/posts/xxxxidxxxxxx"
>             }, 
>             {
>               "name": "Like", 
>               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxidxxxxxx/posts/xxxxidxxxxxxx"
>             }
> {
>               "name": "Comment", 
>               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxidxxxx/posts/xxxxidxxxxxx"
>             }, 
>             {
>               "name": "Like", 
>               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxidxxxxxx/posts/xxxxidxxxxxxx"
>             }
> {
>               "name": "Comment", 
>               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxidxxxx/posts/xxxxidxxxxxx"
>             }, 
>             {
>               "name": "Like", 
>               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxidxxxxxx/posts/xxxxidxxxxxxx"
>             }
>           ],
> ```

Comment: What if I only Need Last 'Name' and 'Link' Leave every one. or second last..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `actions` is an array and it's the only member of `data` in your case.

You just iterating over wrong part, the code should be:

```
foreach($json['data']['actions'] as $action) {
  $name = $action['name'];
  $link = $action['link'];
}
```

Comment: what if i only need last 'name' and 'link' under action or i need second last 'name' and 'link'

Comment: `$json['data']['actions']` is an [`Array`](http://php.net/Array), do whatever you want to it, get the last one by `array_shift`-ing or accessing it by index...

Comment: @Asim, it's really simple to get 3-rd element of array use `$json['data']['actions'][2]` (zero-based index). To get last index you may use something like `count($array)-1`. Hey, [go and learn some arrays](http://php.net/array)!